# Using Bivariate spline with scipy.ndimage.geometric_transform to register images

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy, scikit-image

I am trying to align arrays (images). The arrays do not share homogeneous coordinates due to non-linear distortions and as such an [affine transformation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.affine_transform.html) is not sufficient.

Fortunately it is trivial to find coordinates of matching features between the arrays and these were used to compute an initial affine transformation. I used the residual differences between the coordinate pairs to fit [Smooth Bivariate Splines](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline.html) which then model the position-dependant offset in `x` and `y` that needs to be applied in order to transform one image to the other.

The problem comes when using these Splines with [geometric_transform()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.geometric_transform.html#scipy.ndimage.geometric_transform) - although the resulting alignments are excellent, it is painfully slow (arrays are ~ 50M in size).

I create a spline representing the shifts required in `x` and `y` coordinates (here img1_coo is a Nx2 array of `x` and `y` coordinates in the first image, img2_coo is the same for the second image (after the affine transformation):

```
from scipy import interpolate
sbs_x = interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline(img1_coo[:,0], img1_coo[:,1], img1_coo[:,0]-img2_coo[:,0])
sbs_y = interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline(img1_coo[:,0], img1_coo[:,1], img1_coo[:,1]-img2_coo[:,1])
```

The callable for geometric_transform() is then:

```
def apply_spline(xy):                                                                        
    return xy[0] - sbs_x.ev(xy[0], xy[1]), xy[1] - sbs_y.ev(xy[0], xy[1])
```

Performing the transformation with:

```
from scipy import ndimage
img2_data_splined = ndimage.geometric_transform(img2_data, apply_spline)
```

This takes ~10 minutes on a 50M array. I see that evaluating `SmoothBivariateSpline.ev(x,y)` with 50M size array is very fast:

```
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(8000), np.arange(6000))
%timeit sbs_x.ev(xx,yy)
6.78 s ± 43.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So I guess `geometric_transform()` is being slow in calling each coordinate spearately. For visualisation here are the spline maps I am correcting for (colors goes from ~ -1 pixel to +5 pixels shifts)

[image]

I have tried playing about with lowering the order of the interpolation etc. but not found any speed increases. Any help welcome on speeding up `geometric_transform()` or if there is another implementation to perform image registration and handling complex geometries/distortions?

(I have tried `skimage.warp` using the `PolynomialTransform` but the alignment is not as good and it is also fairly slow, but not as slow as `geometric_transform()`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, there's two solutions for your problem, though potentially only one feasible one:

### 1. Use [`ndimage.map_coordinates`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates.html)

Since `interpolate.SmoothBivariateSpline.ev` is vectorised, in your final expression you are almost already done:

```
from scipy import ndimage as ndi
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(8000), np.arange(6000))
coords_in_input = apply_spline((xx, yy))
img2_data_splined = ndi.map_coordinates(img2_data, coords_in_input)
```

(Note: you may need to do some transposing depending on your coordinate conventions.)

### 2. Use a LowLevelCallable

One reason that `geometric_transform` is taking a while is that [calling functions in Python is slow](https://ilovesymposia.com/2015/12/10/the-cost-of-a-python-function-call/). Pauli Virtanen created the [LowLevelCallable](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.LowLevelCallable.html) interface in SciPy to ensure that C/Cython/Numba functions can be called without the Python overhead. If you can express your mapping function in C or Numba code, you can get big speedups. The [`geometric_transform` docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.geometric_transform.html) tell you the required function signature. Here's a simple example (credit: Kira Evans) for a simple 2D shift:

In Cython:

```
#cython: boundscheck=False
#cython: wraparound=False
#cython: cdivision=True
#cython: nonecheck=False
#cython: initializedcheck=False
#cython: binding=False
#cython: infer_types=False

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as cnp

from libc.stdint cimport intptr_t

cdef api int shift(intptr_t* output_coords, double* input_coords,
                   int output_rank, int input_rank,
                   void* user_data):
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t i

    for i in range(output_rank):
        input_coords[i] = <double> output_coords[i] - (<double*> user_data)[0]

    return 1
```

Then, assuming you've imported the Cython module as `mapping`, in Python:

```
# Don't declare the user_data array inline because
# .ctypes.get_as_parameter
# does not keep reference to the array
shift_amount = np.array([42], dtype=np.double)
shift_cy = LowLevelCallable.from_cython(mapping, name='shift',
               user_data=shift_amount.ctypes.get_as_parameter())
```

Now you can do:

```
shifted = ndi.geometric_transform(image, shift_cy)
```

with decent performance.

You can also use Numba for for this, which might be more or less attractive depending on your use case. See [here](https://ilovesymposia.com/2017/03/12/scipys-new-lowlevelcallable-is-a-game-changer/), [here](https://ilovesymposia.com/2017/03/15/prettier-lowlevelcallables-with-numba-jit-and-decorators/), and [here](https://github.com/jni/llc-tools) for more info.

Comment: Life saver! I was playing about using `map_coordinates` in the `apply_spline` function but of course the cost of calling the function 50M times was still there. Your first answer solved my problem (now takes ~10-15 seconds!) I like the idea of answer 2, I may look at in the future.